# Calculate annual rates from the gam model over time?

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I am trying to express the difference in the 'speed of increase' between two categories in `gam` modelling. My data represents the cumulative values over time [0-100%], but I wish (for comparability with other studies) to express them in yearly values. I wonder if it is even meaningfull, if my models are `gam`, and therefore non-linear?

Previously, to calculated the 'annual values' per two groups by the Compound annual growth rate (CARG) from the starting and ending values/number of years from the `gam` predicted values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808291/compare-the-annual-rates-between-groups). Now, I wonder if **is it somehow possible get those value from the model itselft**, and converted to annual increase? Something, like 'Betas' from 'glm' to show that one predictor is more important then the other?

My data looks like this: I have two groups, with the cumulative rate of forest loss over time (ranging between 0-100% from no forest loss to complete forest loss). Eg. group `yellow` has predicted lost ~ 40 % of forest from 2000 to 2017, group `blue` has predicted lost ~ 10 % over the same time. My dummy data are available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_KX4QUbytcjcBLnkAsJR4FzKMoqcaXa5/view?usp=sharing) and in `dput` form below. My pseudo-code model: `forest_loss ~ year + location`, where different groups represent different location.

```
# Restructure the data first
  dd$grp= as.factor(dd$grp)  # claim grouping variable as factor; represent location
  dd$y <- dd$y/100  # the the values between 0-1, forest loss

# Plot the gam model
   ggplot(dd, aes(x = x, # year 
                y = y, 
                group = grp,
               color = grp)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'gam', 
              method.args = list(family = "betar"),
              formula = y~s(x, bs = 'cs'))  + 
  geom_point()
```

My dummy model is in a formula similar to this: `m1<-bam(y ~ s(x, by = grp) + grp, dd, family = betar)` (I am using the form as used for the real data, althought I have more predictors there), based on `bam/gam`. Family `betar` is because by predicted values ranges between 0-100 (0-1).

This is the dummy example so some part of the code (`gam`) can produce errors. But my main question is **how to express the annual increase per group from the cumulative values themselves?** Is it already accessbible from `summary(m1)`, and it is meaningfull?

Thank you for your thoughts.

The question was originally posted [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73571108/calculate-annual-rates-from-the-gam-model-over-time?noredirect=1#comment130002723_73571108):

[image]

Dummy data [(shared as suggested here using the `dput`)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315885/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-r-data-on-stack-overflow)

```
     dd<- structure(list(x = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L), y = c(2, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.1, 
3.1, 4, 5, 5.6, 5.8, 5.9, 6.7, 7.2, 9, 10, 3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.5, 7, 7.2, 8, 15, 19, 22, 25, 27, 29, 32, 33, 35, 40), grp = c("blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", 
"blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

---

Answer for comments:

somwhow, the `tidymv::plot_smooths(m1)` provides an error:

```
Error in `parse_expr()`:
! `x` must contain exactly 1 expression, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Output from the `summary(m1)`

```
    Family: Beta regression(159982.202) 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
y ~ grp + s(x, by = grp)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -7.76593    0.02992 -259.57   <2e-16 ***
grpyellow    1.05286    0.03648   28.86   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(x):grpblue   2.188  2.726  284.7  <2e-16 ***
s(x):grpyellow 6.184  7.271 1989.4  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.996   Deviance explained = 99.6%
-REML = -276.7  Scale est. = 1         n = 36
```

Partial effect by gratia: `gratia::draw(m1, scales = 'free')`

[image]

Comment: The model you are fitting is not correctly specified; you need `y ~ grp + s(x, by = grp)`. Can you refit that and show the output from that model fit?

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson I have now updated the formula and model output. Please, Can I somehow convert those partial effects (group yeallow, blue) into values per year? or how to interpret the smooths? Thank you!

Comment: I can give you a finite difference based estimate of the slope either for a small finite difference at the values 2000, 20001, etc or a the approximation of the slope over a period of 1 year for all years. See `?gratia::derivatives` and the argument `eps` (set this to be 1 if you want the finite difference to yield a derivative for the year) and the types of finite difference, forwards, backwards, or central. If that's all you want/need I could provide an answer.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, that would be great! I think the *approximation of the slope over a period of 1 year for all years* would be what I am looking for. Can it also be somehow plotted? Thank you again!